# Proof of vector identity

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I have a problem proofing following vector identity:

$$
\nabla \times (\vec a \times \vec b) = (\vec b \cdot \nabla) \vec a + \vec a (\nabla\cdot\vec b)-(\vec a \cdot \nabla)\vec b-\vec b(\nabla \cdot \vec a)
$$

We are supposed to use the Levi-Civita symbol and the Kronecker-Delta. I think it should be relatively easy if you can use 
$$
\vec a \times (\vec b\times\vec c)=\vec b(\vec a\cdot \vec c)-\vec c(\vec a\cdot\vec b)
$$
but I am not sure if you can because of the Nabla.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE**: You cannot use that second identity because $\nabla$ is an *operator*, not a *vector*.  So the two identities are relations about different types of objects.

I'm going to use index notation with the Einstein summation convention.  I'm also using only subscripts instead of superscripts and subscripts, because that's how it's usually taught the first time.  Looking at this, it might be easier starting from the LHS:

$$[\nabla \times (\vec a \times \vec b)]_p = \epsilon_{pqr}\partial_q(\vec a \times \vec b)_r = \epsilon_{pqr}\partial_q\epsilon_{rst}a_sb_t = \epsilon_{pqr}\epsilon_{rst}\partial_qa_sb_t = \epsilon_{rpq}\epsilon_{rst}\partial_qa_sb_t = (\delta_{ps}\delta_{qt} - \delta_{pt}\delta_{sq})\partial_qa_sb_t = \delta_{ps}\delta_{qt}\partial_qa_sb_t - \delta_{pt}\delta_{sq}\partial_qa_sb_t = \partial_qa_pb_q-\partial_qa_qb_p = \dot\partial_q\dot a_pb_q+\dot\partial_qa_p\dot b_q - \dot \partial_q\dot a_qb_p -\dot\partial_qa_q\dot b_p = [(\vec b\cdot \nabla)\vec a + (\nabla \cdot \vec b)\vec a - (\nabla \cdot \vec a)\vec b -(\vec a \cdot \nabla)\vec b]_p$$

And so, because it is true for the $p$th coordinate, it is true for the vectors. $\ \ \square$

BTW, the $\dot \partial_q \dot a_p b_q$ notation means that $b_q$ is held constant in that term.  If you're not used to that notation, you could just use parentheses -- $(\partial_q a_p)b_q$ -- or reorder the factors -- $b_q\partial_q a_p$.  They are all equivalent.

Let me know if you didn't understand one of the steps here.